# File not sending from Angular to Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-blob-storage, mean-stack

I'm using an [ngx-awesome-uploader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-awesome-uploader) to add my images to angular to send to backend. I'm trying to send the file to my nodejs backend, but it keeps returning `{}` on backend where the file should be. Never worked with files before, but I'm gonna take an educated guess and say that should have something in there.

On the frontend it looks like the file is there to be sent because `console.log(fileUpload.file);`

output
[image]

BACKEND OUTPUT

```
File Upload Section
{ file: {}, fileName: 'image.png' }
```

But is empty when received on the backend side as you can see from console output. Not sure why. I appreciate the help!

file-picker.adapter.ts

```
import { FilePreviewModel } from 'ngx-awesome-uploader';
import { HttpRequest, HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FilePickerAdapter } from 'ngx-awesome-uploader';
import { FilePreviewModelWithAuctionId } from './file-upload.model';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export class DemoFilePickerAdapter {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  public uploadFile(fileItem: FilePreviewModel) {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', fileItem.file);

    console.log("FILE OUTPUT");
    console.log(fileItem.file);

    const api = environment.api_url + "/fileupload";
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', api, fileItem, { reportProgress: true });
    return this.http.request(req)
      .pipe(
        map((res: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (res.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            return res.body.id.toString();
          } else if (res.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            // Compute and show the % done:
            const UploadProgress = +Math.round((100 * res.loaded) / res.total);
            return UploadProgress;
          }
        })
      );


  }

}
```

app.js

```
app.post("/api/fileupload", checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {

  console.log("File Upload Section")
  console.log(req.body)


  blobService.createContainerIfNotExists('testcontainer', {
    publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
  }, function (error, result, response) {
    if (!error) {
      // if result = true, container was created.
      // if result = false, container already existed.
    }
  });

  blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('testcontainer', 'taskblob', req.body.file, function (error, result, response) {
    if (!error) {
      // file uploaded
    }
  });



});
```

FilePreviewModel

```
export interface FilePreviewModel {
    fileId?: string;
    file: File | Blob;
    fileName: string;
}
```

FilePreviewModelWithAuctionId

```
export interface FilePreviewModelWithAuctionId {
  fileId?: string;
  file: File | Blob;
  fileName: string;
  auctionId: string;
}
```

Comment: Do you want an answer showing how to do this to azure directly from your client so you can bypass your backend?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify the content type for this reason you cannot find the file.

Add this header to your request.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
let options = { headers: headers, reportProgress: true  };

const api = environment.api_url + "/fileupload";
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', api, form , options );
```

---

**Update** :

I didn't see you are missing the handler for multipart/form-data in your server too.

Follow these steps:

`npm install --save multer`

import multer in your nodejs app :

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({dest: 'public/uploads/'}).single('file');
```

Modify your endpoint :

```
app.post("/api/fileupload", checkAuth, upload, (req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.file);
...
}
```

Comment: I tried both ways, but it still returned ```{}``` Perhaps I did it wrong? https://pastebin.com/pPPQxj37

Comment: Try again with my modified answer.

Comment: It still returns ```{}``` Here's a screenshot of the network tab. It seems to not see headers now https://postimg.cc/pyfqtVY4  Here's my updated code: https://pastebin.com/7cEFJ2RK

Comment: Please retry with updated answer. Let me know if everything is ok.

Comment: I added the your changes and when I send the file to the backend I get ```MulterError: Unexpected field```

Comment: Transform your file as blob

Comment: Check out the frontend console image from original question. It is a blob unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: Can you try to change multer.none() to multer.any(). Thanks

Comment: I changed it and it now outputs from ```console.log("File Upload Section")
  console.log(req.body)```  this: ```File Upload Section [Object: null prototype] {}```  this:

Comment: Im almost sure you are sending a bad request. Can you console log the formData before send it ?

Comment: This code: https://pastebin.com/cSk1jmMU   OUTPUTS: https://postimg.cc/8sfzFKPV

Comment: I'm really tired today, tomorrow i will do a stackblitz + serverside example for you. :)

Comment: This time i tested it, it will work. Update with new change.

Comment: I'm a little swamped today. I'll report back tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Looks promising! So it looks like I'm receiving the file now: https://postimg.cc/xcdfbnq6   . When I try to send it to blob though, it says 
```ArgumentNullError: Required argument blob for function _createBlobFromLocalFile is not defined``` Do you know why that is? Here's the updated code: https://pastebin.com/PMmdh9Br

Comment: Look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cl5gbq this is my test with stackblitz for angular

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt read correctly before, so you recived the file now! oh great! Why are you needing this service? blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile? it isn't a blob yet? look in your public/uploads and check if the file is there

Comment: I'm trying to store the image I get to the backend to Azure blob storage. I'm creating auction site so users need to upload there images to there. So that I can pull them from there later. It'll be much cheaper to store to blob than directly in server folder since there could be 100s of images at some point. File is there: https://postimg.cc/XpFxMHM3

Comment: Try to invert the parameters "req.file" , "MyFile.png".
It say parameter blob is not defined
createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(container, blob, file, options, function(error, result, response)

Comment: I flipped the parameters around to be ```blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('testcontainer', "MYfile.png", req.file, function (error, result, response)```, but got ```TypeError: Parameter localFileName for function _createBlobFromLocalFile should be a non-empty string```

Comment: The most easy solution to this is to point to the path of the file instead to use req.file

Comment: Are you saying the only way this works is I have to store the file on the server first to reference. I can't just pass it along without doing that? Also if that's the case maybe it would be easier to send the file directly from angular.

Comment: From what I read it seems that function takes as input the saved file maybe there is another function or maybe you have to modify the file to make it consistent with the function.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared a form but it's never being in use. Try the following:

```
import { FilePreviewModel } from 'ngx-awesome-uploader';
import { HttpRequest, HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FilePickerAdapter } from 'ngx-awesome-uploader';
import { FilePreviewModelWithAuctionId } from './file-upload.model';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export class DemoFilePickerAdapter {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  public uploadFile(fileItem: FilePreviewModel) {
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', fileItem.file);

    console.log("FILE OUTPUT");
    console.log(fileItem.file);

    const api = environment.api_url + "/fileupload";
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', api, form , { reportProgress: true });
    return this.http.request(req)
      .pipe(
        map((res: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (res.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            return res.body.id.toString();
          } else if (res.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            // Compute and show the % done:
            const UploadProgress = +Math.round((100 * res.loaded) / res.total);
            return UploadProgress;
          }
        })
      );


  }

}
```

Comment: I switched out my code to yours, but it still outputs on the backend ```{}```  no value

Comment: can you inspect the network tab and check if the file content is being sent to /fileupload route?

Comment: It is. If you look at file output at the top. You can see it's outputting the fileName at ```api/fileupload```. Just not the file. Here's the network tab output: https://postimg.cc/G9JQR15g

Comment: there's a difference between console.log and the content of the http request. Click on the second entry (POST)  from your network tab and inspect if the content is actually being posted to the API

Comment: If I click the POST, then this is what outputs: https://postimg.cc/svKCvqvw .

Comment: seems to me it's failing in the authentication (401). Try post to a route without authentication first. (e.g. https://requestbin.com/)

Comment: I created an endpoint with requestbin. It received my POST and outputted: https://pastebin.com/hcu5CaU7