# Send File from Angular to Nodejs - Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, http, azure-functions

I'm having issues passing my data with a file to my nodejs backend. I'm currently using azure functions to run my nodejs code. Currently when I pass the data with file, I'm getting a `Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined` I'm adding the header in the options so I don't really understand why I'm getting the error.` Working with files is definitely one of my weaknesses so I appreciate any help!

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject, Observable } from "rxjs";
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpParams,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpEventType
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { map, takeUntil, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { SendAppealModel } from './send-appeal.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class SubmitAppealService implements OnDestroy {

  destroy = new Subject();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy.next();
    this.destroy.complete();
  }

  submitAppeal(
    username: string,
    email: string,
    file: File
  ) {


    let form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', file);
    form.append('username', username);
    form.append('email', email);

    console.log("FILE OUTPUT");
    console.log(file);

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = { headers: headers, reportProgress: true };

    const api = environment.azure_function_url + `/PATCH-Send-Appeal`;
    const req = new HttpRequest('PATCH', api, form, options);

    return this.http.request(req)
      .pipe(
        map((res: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (res.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            return res.body.id.toString();
          } else if (res.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            // Compute and show the % done:
            const UploadProgress = +Math.round((100 * res.loaded) / res.total);
            return UploadProgress;
          }
        })
      );

  }

}
```

azure function

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'public/uploads/' }).single('file');

module.exports = function (context, req) {
  context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
  upload();


  console.log(req.file);
  var filename = path.basename("../" + req.file.path);
  console.log("filename");
  console.log(req.file.destination);
  console.log(__dirname);

  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  console.log("form");
  console.log(form);


  context.res = {
    status: 200,

    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PATCH, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Set-Cookie',
      'Access-Control-Max-Age': '86400',
      Vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Origin',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };


  context.done();
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are getting that error because your `headers` aren't actually making it to your azure function.

Currently you have this:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
let options = { headers: headers, reportProgress: true };
```

You can't do that. `headers.append` doesn't do an in-place update. It *returns* a new `HttpHeaders` object. So, you actually need this:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
headers = headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
let options = { headers: headers, reportProgress: true };
```

Per comments, I see one other thing that looks a little off to me. This may be part of the issue. Try updating your HTTP call to this:

const req = new HttpRequest('PATCH', api, form, options);

```
return this.http.patch(api, form, options)
  .pipe(
    map((res: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (res.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        return res.body.id.toString();
      } else if (res.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        // Compute and show the % done:
        const UploadProgress = +Math.round((100 * res.loaded) / res.total);
        return UploadProgress;
      }
    })
  );
```

You might also set a breakpoint in your azure function on the first line to inspect the request object and make sure your `HttpHeaders` are making it in.

Comment: I'm changed my code to reflect your answer, but I'm getting the same error still. Updated Code: https://pastebin.com/5EKT2BrU

Comment: To clarify, you're getting the above error in your node code, not angular. Correct? If so, please paste the full stracktrace.

Comment: correct it's a backend error. Here you go: https://pastebin.com/jQpJ0abs

Comment: Hm.... wierd. I see one other thing that looks weird. Updated my question.

Comment: I'd also be interested in what the `upload()` function is doing. It'd also be helpful to know how far you can debug you node function (ie: What line is that exception thrown on)

Comment: The upload() references this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213312/file-not-sending-from-angular-to-nodejs/60403448#60403448      I was trying to mirror the equivalent to ```app.post("/api/fileupload", checkAuth, upload, (req, res, next) => {``` within an azure function syntax friendly way. while following that answers instructions. I don't fully understand the upload() from the answer to be honest.

Comment: My guess is that the function could be messed up. azure is picky about how it's function apps are structured. I would create a working "hello world" function and make sure that works, then add in your file upload code piece-by-piece. The `checkAuth` thing looks a bit interesting too. Maybe the function isn't anonymous and therefore requires authentication headers and you aren't passing them? I would assume this error would be 401 though....